# MAGIMAGEHEADER in java

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I am creating class for [MAGIMAGEHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692384(v=vs.85).aspx) in Java

The Structure of MAGIMAGEHEADER in Winapi is

```
typedef struct tagMAGIMAGEHEADER {
  UINT               width;
  UINT               height;
  WICPixelFormatGUID format;
  UINT               stride;
  UINT               offset;
  SIZE_T             cbSize;
} MAGIMAGEHEADER, *PMAGIMAGEHEADER;
```

I have created a equivalent class in Java.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MAGIMAGEHEADER extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public Object format;
    public int stride;
    public int offset;
    public int cbsize;

    public List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("width","height","format","stride","offset","cbsize");
    }
}
```

I have problem with `format` field, How to define WICPixelFormatGUID in Java?

I didn't find any structure of `WICPixelFormatGUID` in winapi.

Comment: Did you read this? *The MAGIMAGEHEADER structure is deprecated in Windows 7 and later, and should not be used in new applications. There is no alternate functionality.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation to which you link, the type is declared in `wincodec.h`. Search for the type there and you find:

```
typedef /* [public] */ GUID WICPixelFormatGUID;
```

So, it is, not surprisingly, a `GUID`.

I believe that means you need to use [`com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Guid.GUID`](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Guid.GUID.html).