# MagSetImageScalingCallback definition in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm searching for a right definition of [`MagSetImageScalingCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) api to VB.NET but until now nothing was found on web. Someone could say how could be the signature of this function?

Here is a "mirror" in C++:

```
typedef BOOL (CALLBACK* MagImageScalingCallback)(HWND hwnd, void * srcdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER srcheader, void * destdata, MAGIMAGEHEADER destheader, RECT unclipped, RECT clipped, HRGN dirty ); 

BOOL WINAPI MagSetImageScalingCallback(HWND hwnd, MagImageScalingCallback callback );
```

- [Reference](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=33&topic=10477&start=1560&limit=1&m=1)

Comment: _"The **MagSetImageScalingCallback** function is **deprecated** in Windows 7 and later, and should not be used in new applications. There is no alternate functionality"_ - Are you really using Windows Vista or earlier?

Comment: Either way have you looked over at https://www.pinvoke.net/ ?

Comment: @VisualVincent, i will use `MagSetImageScalingCallback` only on Win 10. And not is possible find the definition in [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/).

Comment: But why? Like I quoted from the MSDN article _that you linked to_ `MagSetImageScalingCallback` is deprecated as of Windows 7. You shouldn't use it. One day there might come an update that removes the feature (a lot of old features have been removed in various W10 updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Structure RECT
    Public Left As Int32
    Public Top As Int32
    Public Right As Int32
    Public Bottom As Int32
End Structure

Public Structure MAGIMAGEHEADER
    Public width As UInteger
    Public height As UInteger
    Public format As Guid 'Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31890584/9672569
    Public stride As UInteger
    Public offset As UInteger
    Public cbSize As UInteger
End Structure

Private Delegate Function ImageScalingCallback(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal srcdata As IntPtr, ByVal srcheader As MAGIMAGEHEADER, ByRef destdata As IntPtr, ByVal destheader As MAGIMAGEHEADER, ByVal unclipped As RECT, ByVal clipped As RECT, ByVal dirty As IntPtr) As Boolean

 <DllImport("Magnification.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
    Private Shared Function MagSetImageScalingCallback(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal callback As ImageScalingCallback) As Boolean
    End Function
```